# MySql produced CSV file has all columns stacked in the first column

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, into-outfile

My MySql query is working fine and I am getting CSV output. The problem is the CSV file columns look like stacked in a single cell. I have total 24 columns. I confirmed it by opening in the Python and MS office.

**MySql Query:**

```
SELECT 'datetime','col2',...,'col24'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DateTime','col2',...,'col24' 
INTO OUTFILE "SampleData.csv" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n';
```

**My present output when opened in the MS office:**

You see all the 24 columns data stacked in the first column `A` here.
[image]

**My present output when opened in the Python:**

The python also shows same response

```
df = pd.read_csv('SampleData.csv')
print(df.shape)
(0,1)
```

Expected output:

```
(1740,24)
```

**UPDATE**
@FanoFN suggestions below, I found my mistake. Adding I made one more important and everything worked perfectly.
My query:

```
SELECT 'datetime','col2',...,'col24'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DateTime','col2',...,'col24' 
INTO OUTFILE "SampleData.csv" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY "" # Here I deleted the ,
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' # Here I corrected /n to \n
;
```

In Python:
df = pd.read_csv(SampleData.csv) # no need to specify the delimiters
Result:

[image]

Comment: My above problem solved: I just removed last three lines in the MySql Query and  in Python I used `\t` delimiter while importing the data.

Comment: I have a question: when to use or not to use the three lines `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n';` while downloading the data?

Comment: My test shows that with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n';` options, I actually get each column in their own cell but all of them are in a single row. Without those three options, the csv output is the same as your present output where everything is in a single cell but each row to itself according to the total rows from the query.

Comment: By the way, the `/n` is suppose to be `\n`.

Comment: @FanoFN Yes Now I everything worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I also made one more change in mysql query.  I have put `ENCLOSED  BY " "`. That's it. My question is, when and how to use them?  How should I know it? Thanks

Comment: I think you should always use them because without it, the csv output doesn't really make sense since there's no separation between the columns, right?